# Transitive efficient comparison and value assignment to dataframe variables in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, controls, comparison

I have 3 data frames:

df1:

```
    key       value
1   rs1057079     C
2   rs4845882     A
3   rs1891932     T
4    rs530296     A
5  rs10497340     G
```

df2:

```
    key       value
1   rs1057079     T
2   rs4845882     G
3   rs1891932     T
4    rs530296     A
5  rs10497340     A
```

and third control df3:

```
    key       value
1   rs1057079     C
2   rs4845882     A
3   rs1891932     C
4    rs530296     G
5  rs10497340     G
```

I want to check for all keys in `df1` and `df2` if they are equal or not to the control `df3`. For example check if `df1$rs1057079 == df3$rs1057079`, same with `df2`.

I want to do this without a for loop, what is the most simple and efficient way?
I thought about dplyr filter and mutate functions but will be happy to hear from the experts how to compare n df's to a control df?

Comment: The best process really depends on the output and how you're planning to use it in the future. To start with, what do you want to do if the keys are equal to the control ones? Create a flag column like Yes/No to the datasets? Create a new dataset that has only those keys? Something else?

Comment: @AntoniosK Yes I want to code it in 0,1,2 in other df.

Comment: Not sure I got that. What do those 3 values represent and how you expect the output to be? Can you describe the process a bit further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll create a function that takes two datasets (test and control) and returns the values (next to each other) and a flag to spot when they are the same.

```
df1 = read.table(text = "
key       value
1   rs1057079     C
2   rs4845882     A
3   rs1891932     T
4    rs530296     A
5  rs10497340     G
", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

df2 = read.table(text = "
key       value
1   rs1057079     T
2   rs4845882     G
3   rs1891932     T
4    rs530296     A
5  rs10497340     A
", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

df3 = read.table(text = "
key       value
1   rs1057079     C
2   rs4845882     A
3   rs1891932     C
4    rs530296     G
5  rs10497340     G
", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)


library(dplyr)

# function that compares the values based on the key column
CompareDatasets = function(d1, d2) {
d1 %>%
  left_join(d2, by="key") %>%
  mutate(IsSame = value.x == value.y)
}

# apply function
CompareDatasets(df1, df3)

#          key value.x value.y IsSame
# 1  rs1057079       C       C   TRUE
# 2  rs4845882       A       A   TRUE
# 3  rs1891932       T       C  FALSE
# 4   rs530296       A       G  FALSE
# 5 rs10497340       G       G   TRUE
```

Column `key` represents both datasets, `value.x` is the value of the test dataset, `value.y` is the value of the control dataset (depends on which dataset you pass first to the function) and `flag` spot when values are equal.

Another way to do this is by creating a single dataframe output (i.e. compare all test datasets with control at the same time), but you need to create a column with the dataset name:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# fucntion that gets the name of a dataset and returns the dataset with the name as a column
GetNameData = function(x) {
  d = get(x)
  d$name = x
  d
}

# vector of test datsets' names (multiple names)
# df3 will be the control
test = c("df1", "df2")

test %>%                                    # get the dataset names
  map_df(GetNameData) %>%                   # apply the function and get data (single dataframe)
  left_join(df3, by="key") %>%              # join the control group
  mutate(IsSame = value.x == value.y) %>%   # flag equal values
  select(name, everything())                # re-arrange columns

#    name        key value.x value.y IsSame
# 1   df1  rs1057079       C       C   TRUE
# 2   df1  rs4845882       A       A   TRUE
# 3   df1  rs1891932       T       C  FALSE
# 4   df1   rs530296       A       G  FALSE
# 5   df1 rs10497340       G       G   TRUE
# 6   df2  rs1057079       T       C  FALSE
# 7   df2  rs4845882       G       A  FALSE
# 8   df2  rs1891932       T       C  FALSE
# 9   df2   rs530296       A       G  FALSE
# 10  df2 rs10497340       A       G  FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

If we can assume that all keys present in df1 and df2 will be present in df3, and they are sorted in the same order, the solution is fairly straightforward:

```
df1$value==df3$value
df2$value==df3$value
```

This output a vector of TRUE and FALSE where every element is the answer for a line in df1 and df2.